# Navigation after a future when using riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, riverpod, riverpod-generator

There is a Future/Provider that call an API and then return some data

```dart
@riverpod
Future<UserModel> updateProfile(
  UpdateProfileRef ref, {
  required String? firstName,
  required String? lastName,
  required String? birthDate,
}) async {
  ref.keepAliveUntilNoListeners();

  final repository = ref.read(profileRepositoryProvider);
  final result = await repository.updateUserProfile(
    UpdateProfileInputModel(
      data: InputProfileInputUpdate(
        birthDate: birthDate,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
      ),
    ),
  );

  return result.fold(
    Future.error,
    (r) => r,
  );
}
```

And this is the button that watch to this provider

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {
    return LoadingButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          ref
              .watch(
                updateProfileProvider(
                  firstName: firstNameController.text,
                  lastName: lastNameController.text,
                  birthDate: dateValue,
                ),
              )
              .when(
                data: (data) {
                  context.pop();
                },
                error: (error, stackTrace) => print,
                loading: () => log('loading'),
              );
        }
      },
      height: 48.h,
      title: l10n.saveEditedInfo,
    );
  },
),
```

This implementation has issue and the app doesn't navigate.

I have some question about it ...
Where is the correct place, and where should I listen to changes and show some toast for errors or navigate for success futures?
I know that there is a `ref.listen` method, but it calls the future and I can't use it in build method, because I want to call future when user presses the button.

---

## New update

I changed the provider to this:

```dart
@riverpod
Future<UserModel> updateProfile(
  UpdateProfileRef ref, {
  required String? firstName,
  required String? lastName,
  required String? birthDate,
}) async {
  final repository = ref.read(profileRepositoryProvider);
  final result = await repository.updateUserProfile(
    UpdateProfileInputModel(
      data: InputProfileInputUpdate(
        birthDate: birthDate,
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
      ),
    ),
  );
  return result;
}
```

Also use it in the UI like this :

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {
    return LoadingButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          changeLoadingValue(state: true);
          await ref
              .read(
            updateProfileProvider(
              firstName: firstNameController.text,
              lastName: lastNameController.text,
              birthDate: dateValue,
            ).future,
          )
              .then(
            (value) {
              ref.invalidate(homeWhoAmIProvider);
              context.go(HomeScreen.path);
            },
          ).catchError((e) {
            changeLoadingValue(state: false);
            showToast(context, title: e.toString());
          });
        }
      },
      isLoading: buttonLoading,
      height: 48.h,
      title: l10n.saveEditedInfo,
    );
  },
),
```

Actually I am waiting for the result or error of the future then navigate or handle the error.
Now it works, but I don't know is it normal to handle this case like this or not.(I am looking for a better approach to handle navigation or error handling...)

Comment: Providers should not have side effects in its body. To perform side effects, see [this](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/side_effects). Also you can wait for a provider to complete its future value, for example `await ref.read(myProvider.future)`

Comment: What does "ref.keepAliveUntilNoListeners()" do?  That's the default behavior.  What extra code are you running?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz It's an extension on `AutoDisposeRef` to keep listening to an autoDispose provider until the last listener is removed, but I don't need it in this case, I added it while debugging and testing and forgot to remove it.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I did some change, also I am using `await ref.read(xxx.future)` but I don't know is it correct to handle navigation or error handling in the UI like this!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy that you solved it like that. However, you can also use listener  inside ***Consumer*** or ***ConsumerWidget***, that Riverpod provides you

For instance;

```
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {
    ref.listen(
      internetConnectionResultProvider,
      (_, state) async {
        LogHelper.shared.debugPrint(state.name);
        switch (state) {
          case ConnectivityStatus.notDetermined:
          // You logic goes here

          case ConnectivityStatus.connected:
          // You logic goes here

          case ConnectivityStatus.disonnected:
            // You logic goes here
            break;
        }
      },
    );
    return SomeRelatedWidget();
  },
);
```

Give me a feedback after you try. Cheers

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I think it is not the correct approach in my case because when we listen to a `Future Provider`, it calls automatically. But in my case, I need to call it when the user clicks on a specific button.